# new ArrayList() as an argument to a map.put() is an unsafe operation?

Tags: java, arraylist, new-operator, unsafe

The following code:

```
for (String day:daysOfWeek) {classesData.put(day, new ArrayList());}
```

gives me the following error:

```
Note: ./com/myname/MyClass/MyClass1.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.                                                                
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

I had to manually comment a lot of lines to see that the code above was the one with error. I suspect it's because of `classesData.put(day, new ArrayList());`, more specifically, `new ArrayList()`. I'm starting `new ArrayList()` because I want to add things in the future, now now. I add like this:

```
classesData.get(trueDayName).add(hourData);
```

(hourData is a Map)

because classesData is the following data structure:

```
Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> classesData = new HashMap<String, List<Map<String, String>> >();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArrayList` in Java is a generic type and you're omitting the generics completely and using it as a [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).  I'm not certain, but this could be the reason for your issue.

Try:  `classesData.put(day, new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>());`